# difference between "applications" folder and the "hot-deploy" folders in ofbiz?

Tags: apache, web-applications, ofbiz

I'm new to ofbiz. I create an application in my "ofbiz/hot-deploy" folder. In some site, books they mention our application should be present in "applications" folders also. But I don't know the difference between put user defined  applications in the folders namely "hot-deploy" and "applications" in ofbiz.

Please tell the difference, because it will be very useful to my project. Please forgive my mistakes in my questions because I'm new to ofbiz .

Thanks & Regards,
Sivakumar.J

Answer (score 3, accepted):

applications is where the **OOTB apps provided with the OFBiz framework** like marekting, order, party reside. It is best **NOT** to put your stuff there so you can forward integrate with the next version of Ofbiz.

application components: they are generic applications that can be used as they are or extended/customized (product, order, party, manufacturing, accounting etc…); application components have access to the services and tools provided by the framework components and to the services published by other application components

hot-deploy is where **you put your custom application** which also has access to the services underlying from the framework.

So if you make a new application say SivakumarWebApp then place it in the hot-deploy, and it can access the framework components as well as other application components.

http://www.hotwaxmedia.com/apache-ofbiz-blog/ofbiz-tutorial-custom-components-in-ofbiz/

Comment: Sorry josek, im new to ofbiz.So i cannot understand ur explainations.I also visit the link u specified.But im not able to understand.So please send more details with some examples with respect to my level.Because im new to ofbiz,I had no knowledge in ofbiz.